# Is area integral and area weighted mean possible with xarray?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I am new to xarray and I need this functionality often to analyze an output of a general circulation model. I can do this with numpy, but I wonder if a shortcut functions for weighted mean and integral along coordinates, are already implemented in xarray? If not, is there a plan to include them into a future release, or should they belong to packages built on top of xarray?

Comment: can you provide some example (pseudo) code that demonstrates what you are trying to do and how/why xarray doesn't seem to be able to do what you want?

Comment: The use cases are for example computing a global mean surface temperature or total surface heat flux from 2d data. Weights should be taken into account since size of grid cells depend on geographic location. It is fairly simple to write such functions, but I thought that since it is commonly used analysis, somebody may already have implemented such capability in xarray. The answer of shoyer below makes everything clear.

Comment: For area weighted integration or averaging, also consider the `cdutil` module in the `cdat` project (https://github.com/CDAT/cdutil). You would do something like `a_mean=cdutil.averager(data, axis='xy', weights=['generate', 'generate'])`. It also works with the time dimension, e.g. giving different weights to monthly data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple use cases, [weighted averaging](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/422) and [integrals](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1288) have been discussed for xarray, but not implemented yet. Help would be appreciated! (Please reach out on GitHub to discuss details.)

For your specific needs, [xgcm](https://github.com/xgcm/xgcm) might be worth a look. It includes utilities for doing these sort of transformations on native GCM grids.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'll look through github discussion.

Comment: Both proposed solutions for for weighted averaging and integral look good enough to me, why aren't they included into release?

Comment: The short answer is that nobody has finished them up into polished pull request yet, with documentation, tests and a carefully considered API design. In cases like these, the actual code implementation is only a small part of the work. We would certainly welcome help from someone interested in this, such as yourself!